# Selecting the most recent row from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a basic forum, and i want to grab the list of threads created but also grab the `most recent post` from the post table so i can display `last reply and time of last reply`

How ever my attempt is causing duplicate results, i tried a `LEFT JOIN` and a `INNER JOIN` with the same outcome. I was hoping someone knew the solution.

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT  t1.username as thread_starter,
        t2.username as last_reply_username,
        t1.thread_time as thread_start,
        t2.post_time as last_reply_time,
        t1.title,
        t1.sticky 
FROM threads t1
     INNER JOIN posts t2
        ON t1.id = t2.threadid
ORDER BY t1.sticky DESC, t2.post_time DESC
```

Does any one know how i can solve the problem so it will only get the last and most recent post from the post table related to each thread without returning duplicate threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind the query below is that it finds the most recent post (`post_time`) from the `post` table for each `threadid` inside the subquery. Then it joins back on the original table `post` and `threads` table.

```
SELECT  a.username AS Thread_Starter,
        c.username AS Last_reply_username,
        a.thread_time AS Thread_Start,
        c.post_time AS Last_Reply_Time,
        a.Title,
        a.Sticky
FROM    threads a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  threadID, MAX(Post_Time) lastPost
            FROM    post
            GROUP BY ThreadID
        ) b ON  a.threadID = b.threadID
        INNER JOIN post c
            ON  b.threadID = c.ThreadID AND
                b.lastPost = c.post_time
ORDER BY a.sticky DESC, c.post_time DESC
```